# Al hacer push a un array de objetos se remplaza en ves de insertar uno nuevo

Tags: reactjs, expo, react-router-dom

Estoy tratando de hacer push en un hook, pero por alguna razón solo lo actualiza en ves de insertar un nuevo dato

```
const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([]);

async function addItemToCart(itemImage,
    itemName,
    itemPrice,
    itemId) {

    let shoppingCart = {
        itemImage: itemImage,
        itemName: itemName,
        itemCuantity: 1,
        itemPrice: itemPrice
    };
```

De esta manera actualiza en ves de insertar

```
setCart([...cart, shoppingCart])
```

De esta manera tambien susede lo mismo

```
cart.push(shoppingCart)
```

Este es el botón que ejecuta esa función:

```
}

return (
    <Container >
        <Button block style={styles.btnColor} onPress={() => addItemToCart(item.itemImage, item.itemName, item.itemPrice)}>
            <Text>COMPRAR</Text>
        </Button>
    </Container>
);
```

Quiero aclarar que al usar useEffect de esta manera para que actualize el cart la pagina deja de funcionar pero cuando lo uso en expo funciona perfectamente.

```
useEffect(() => {
}, [cart]);
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que los llamados al hook `setState` no son siempre síncronos, esto quiere decir que cuando tu ejecutas `setState`, el cambio del estado no es inmediato. Existen diferentes situaciones por las cuales el cambio de estado puede ser aplazado para realizarse en un tiempo posterior pero lo importante es que si tu realizas dos `setState` de la manera como los estas realizando, es posible que cuando se realize el cambio, ambos vean el mismo estado inicial, es decir, si en un principio el carrito estaba vacío, ambos van a tener `cart` como un arreglo vacío, y ambos `setState` van a poner su respectivo item como primer elemento, resultando en que pareciera que solo una de las dos inserciones tiene efecto.

Para corregir este efecto es posible pasar una función a `setState`. Esta función toma como parámetro el estado anterior de cuando es realmente ejecutada y debe retornar el nuevo estado derivado de ese estado anterior. Esto permite que los `setState` se encadenen y eviten tener un estado incorrecto por razones de que fueron aplazados.

Básicamente en vez de `setCart([...cart, shoppingCart])`, seria `setCart(cart => [...cart, shoppingCart])`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Con tu respuesta ahora tengo que dar dos click para que guarde pero hace lo mismo solo remplaza el primer item en el array, tener en cuenta que esto es un componente que que es una tarjeta de items de compra de productos y esta siendo renderiza en un .map, cuando recargo la pagina si acepta un nuevo item.